# Interesting array of letters

Tags: arrays, r, rstudio

was practicing the basic operation and finding something interesting.

```
test <- array(0,dim = c(1,26))
colnames(test) <- letters
```

I was expecting an array with letters as colname, yet it turns out to be like this

[image]

the name of 24th column shall be "x" undoubtfully, while the result is not.
interesting.
Eric

Comment: Just for my sanity, what does colnames(test) return?

Comment: letters might have been modified. did you check it to see what's actually in it?

Comment: Cant reproduce using R or View(test) from terminal, but can reproduce using  View in Rstudio.

Comment: hmm rstudio View doesnt seem to like `"x"` column name in matrices `silly=matrix(0, ncol=1, dimnames = list(NULL, "x")) ; View(silly)` but okay in data.frames `View(data.frame(silly))`

Comment: This should be submitted as a bug in the RStudio support forums. It works fine in console print and in `View()` in console R and R.app (which do the same thing). Somewhere in RStudio's code there's a bug in interpreting `x` in this context. It even fails in latest daily version.

Comment: I am not sure if somebody already opened an issue for this. I just created one here - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3304

Comment: so far no one really answered. Guess ppl feel interesting, but not really care. ;-) and of course, thanks.

Comment: @Grec001 You have failed to ask a question. So that is possibly why you have no answers! :D But seriously, this is known as "a bug", there is no answer to be had. Raise it in their bug tracking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question and it's just pointing out a bug.